# Does an interface by default extend Object?

Tags: java

If you define a interface like below

```
interface I1{

}
```

The in any code section you can write like

```
I1 i1;
i1.equals(null);
```

Then from where the equals method come, is the interface also extends the super class Object ?, if that true how an interface can extends a class?

Suppose let the interface extends the super class Object , then if you see why the collection interface like Set thave define the  equals() and hashCode() method ?. All the class extends the Object class so if you define any abstract method in a interface which present in Object class then who implement the interface they no need to implements those method. Like in below code

```
interface I1{
String toString();
}

class A implements I1{

}
```

Here the class A no need to implements the method toString() as it's present in Object class.
Then what is the objective  of defining those method in collection interface as they can't force there implementation class to implement those method.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Then from where the equals method come, is the interface also extends the super class Object ?, if that true how an interface can extends a class?

The Java Language Specification deals with this explicitly.

From [section 9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

Basically, this is so that you *can* use `equals`, `hashCode` etc - because the way that the Java language is specified means that any concrete implementation of the interface *will* be a class, and that class *must* ultimately be a subclass of `Object`, so the members will definitely be present.

To put it another way, while the interface itself doesn't extend `Object`, it is known that any implementation will.

> Here the class A no need to implements the method toString() as it's present in Object class. Then what is the objective of defining those method in collection interface as they can't force there implementation class to implement those method.

Usually this is just done for clarity, e.g. to document what is expected of an implementation in terms of the members declared in `Object`.

Comment: Thank you very much So we can say that interfcae do not extend the object class, What is the answer of my second questions about Set interface why they have define those method.

Comment: @KrushnaCh.Dash: See the end of my answer. The documentation for `Set.hashCode` and `Set.equals` provide more details about the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Every class implicitly extends `Object` and so inherits every (non-private) method of the Object class.

Every instance has a class and therefore has all of the method of Object.

Whether an instance implements an interface or not is completely irrelevant to this point.

Object is a class, and interfaces can not extend classes, so "no" - the interface doesn't inherit anything from any class.

Comment: Well, OP is talking about interfaces.

Comment: @RohitJain better now? I thought what I was dayin

Comment: But what about this? In the interface, you can override all public methods from class Object.

Answer (score 0):

A Java Interface does not extend the `java.lang.Object` class but instances of objects that implement the interface extend the Object class otherwise if Java Interfaces allowed to extend the `java.lang.Object` class then Java would support multiple inheritance of which it does not in its language specification.

Consider the scenario below:

```
interface MyInterface
{ 
   // interface methods here
}
MyClass extend java.lang.Object implements MyInterface
{ 
   // override methods or interface method implementations
}
```

Now if MyInterface extends `java.lang.Object` class then that would mean the MyClass would also be extending the MyInterface interface by construction creating multiple inheritance. So makes sense that Java interfaces do not extend the `java.lang.Object` class as this would create chaos due to multiple inheritance.