# Compiler Prefers Object's Method to Implementation

Tags: java, eclipse

I came over a strange behavior of the Eclipse compiler today and I'm not sure what to think of it. We're trying to create a useful `Cloneable` interface like that:

```
public interface PublicCloneable extends Cloneable {

    Object clone();

    static <T extends PublicCloneable> T clone(final T obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            return (T) obj.clone();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The fun part is that the compiler complains about `obj.clone()`: `Unhandled exception type CloneNotSupportedException`

I know how to fix it, we can just cast `obj` to `PublicCloneable` and be done with it. But what I'm interested in: why would the compiler prefer the method of `Object` to a method of an implementation?

Comment: The compiler during compile-time just checks whether the method being called exists in the top-most class in the hierarchy. It doesn't *resolve* calls to actual concrete classes.

Comment: @TheLostMind What's the difference? The top-most class is still `PublicCloneable` not `Object`.

Comment: No. the compiler checks whether the method is defined in one of the superclasses of `PublicCloneable`. During Runtime, the actual call will be resolved to the `clone()` method of the Concrete class. Simple put, the compiler doesn't care whether *Your concrete class* actually ahs that method. all it wants to know is that someone in the class hierarchy of your class should ahve it. The moment it finds it, it says - *Code is fine* !

Comment: @TheLostMind So the compiler resolves it in excactly the opposite direction as the runtime execution? That's crazy! o_O

Comment: The compiler just checks for its existance.. Thats all :P

Comment: @TheLostMind If I change the type of the argument from `T` to `PublicCloneable` it works as expected, but according to that logic, it should find the protected method first as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776045/896588

> [...] while the interface itself doesn't extend Object, it is known that any implementation will.

So since you have an interface, the declared `clone()` doesn't override the `clone()` of `Object`. It is formally a newly declared operation at this point.

Try implementing your interface. You will see that it forces you to override `clone()` from `Object` but without the exception since it also has to fulfill the interface.

You have created a tricky and complex situation here. The compiler knows that your implementing class will also extend `Object` and inherit `clone()` with the exception. When it looks for a declaration in the type hierachy, it finds that one first and stops searching. It doesn't care anymore that `PublicCloneable` (which will have a `clone()` without exception) is in the type hierachy too. If you change the parameter type directly to `PublicCloneable`, that's where it start searching and finds the other one.

This might be explained too simplified but I can't seem to find the corresponding formal parts in the JLS.